# see Wikipedia articles on a Map - free alternative to 5$ Viki app (Reader for Wikipedia)

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, software-recommendation

I wish to see Wikipedia articles on a map. Explore local Wikipedia articles. The app [Viki](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/viki-nice-reader-for-wikipedia/id993435362?mt=8) offers that feature.

> NEARBY PLACES: Discover interesting Wikipedia articles about the area
>   around your location. Or explore any other spot in the world. It’s fun
>   with Viki’s unique map visualization.

Is there a free alternative? Maybe web based? I found with a search engine a OpenStreetMap project, but sadly not a ready-to-use product.

Answer (score 2):

[WikiLinks](http://wikilinks.net/home/) is free and shows articles about your surroundings. Although it doesn't have a map view, it lists articles about points of interest near your location sorted by distance. Also includes international results for languages you pick.